# AngularJS: How to allow/enable a directive when controller X is active?

Tags: angularjs, directive

or in other words: how can I stop/destroy a directive when the controller X is not active anymore?

I need that feature so that I can prevent directives from "running" when routing to a different page. Been studying your documentation but couldn't find an answer to that simple question.

Here is the HTML/Jade code for the directive:

```
doctype html
html(data-ng-app="videomailApp")
    body
        main(data-ng-view, data-ng-cloak)
            h2 Changelog
            ul#changelog(data-ng-highlightVersion)
                each version, i in versions
                    li(id=version.number)
                        h3
                            a(href="#" + version.number) Version #{version.number}
                            if i === 0
                                |&nbsp;[current]
                        | !{version.changelog}
```

Then my custom, browserified, AngularJS directive to highlight the currently selected version is as following:

```
module.exports = function($location) {
    return function($scope, $element) {

        var versions   = $element.children(),
            onClass    = 'current',
            versionMap = {},

            $currentVersion,
            $version,
            i

        for (i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
            $version = angular.element(versions[i])
            versionMap[$version.attr('id')] = $version
        }

        /*
            Problems to solve:
            - how can i enable this directive only when on that page?
            - the event below is not fired on page load
            - if nothing works, consider moving all that to the controller which is much easier
        */

        $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            var id = $location.hash()

            var $version = versionMap[id]

            if ($version) {
                if ($currentVersion)
                    $currentVersion.removeClass(onClass)

                $currentVersion = $version
                $currentVersion.addClass(onClass)
            }
        })
    } }
```

I load the directive in main.js with this

```
app.directive('highlightVersion', ['$location', require('./directives/highlightVersion')])
```

Like I mentioned, it looks like this directive is always running, no matter if that page is active or if the user has changed the route to another page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you seeing any specific problem? Directive lifetime is closely tied to the lifetime of its container view.

Comment: You are writing a custom directive and want to destroy it when navigate to another route?

Comment: Yes @runTarm that's what I want.

Comment: @metacubed interesting - is there an example which demonstrates the lifetime of a custom directive?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `ng-if` attribute which will remove/create dom.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: I don't see how this can help with my directive issue.